# Discord,js v14 Error with GatewayIntgentBits.Guilds

Tags: javascript, discord.js

In the process of learning JavaScript and while doing so, I've been messing with Discord bot tutorials. With version 14, I'm getting an error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Guild')`. I have everything installed for v14 from what's listed on discord.js and not sure what I'm missing for this error. Sample code I've been working with:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { TOKEN } = process.env;
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
client.commands = new Collection();
client.commandArray = [];

const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
  const functionFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(`./src/function/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of functionFiles)
    require(`./functions${folder}/${file}`)(client);
}

client.handleEvents();
client.hanldeCommands();
client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. (and it's weird that it says `(reading 'Guild')`, but it's probably just a typo). Are you sure you're using v14?

Comment: Unless I missed something, I'm on V14. I switched to my old code and it doesn't work (no issues before) - updated Node.js and removed @discordjs/builders. Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: You can check your `package.json` file or just import the `version` like this: `const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits, version } = require("discord.js");` and add `console.log(version)` somewhere.

Comment: Sooo, looks like I don't have v14 installed: `"discord.js": "^13.9.1"` Running in my main file gives the same error but looking in package.json, shows what's listed above.

Comment: Smh, lol.. I uninstalled and reinstalled and it updated to the latest version. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP has already solved this but adding this answer for sake of other people who come across the question.

You should double check that you are actually running discord.js on the correct version, you can do so doing a couple of things, you can look at the `package.json` file and look for an entry that starts with `discord.js` and will look something like this

```json
"discord.js": "^14.0.2",
```

You can also run `npm list discord.js` in your terminal and view the result there as well.